# subprocess.run not suppressing all console output

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, python-3.7, console-output

`subprocess.run` with `stdout=DEVNULL` and `stderr=STDOUT` does not suppress all output from the [subinacl.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510) utility.

```
>>> # Do not suppress: OK
>>> subprocess.run('subinacl.exe /service "foo" display', shell=True)
foo - OpenService Error : 1060 The specified service does not exist as an installed service.



Elapsed Time: 00 00:00:00
Done:        1, Modified        0, Failed        1, Syntax errors        0
Last Done  : foo
Last Failed: foo - OpenService Error : 1060 The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

CompletedProcess(args='subinacl.exe /service "foo" display', returncode=0)

>>> # Suppress: Some output is still printed
>>> subprocess.run('subinacl.exe /service "foo" display', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

Elapsed Time: 00 00:00:00
Done:        1, Modified        0, Failed        1, Syntax errors        0
Last Done  : foo
Last Failed: foo - OpenService Error : 1060 The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

CompletedProcess(args='subinacl.exe /service "foo" display', returncode=0)
>>>
```

My guess is that subinacl.exe is calling another process that prints the output that is not being suppressed. Don't `stdout=DEVNULL` and `stderr=STDOUT` silence output from the whole process chain?

Comment: There's no need for `shell=True` here since you're not running a shell command.

Comment: Overriding the standard handles doesn't stop a process from opening the console's active screen buffer (i.e. "CONOUT$") or creating a new screen buffer via `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`. If you don't want any visible output, you have three options:

Comment: (1) Use `creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS` to run it without a console session; you should redirect all unused standard handles to `DEVNULL` in this case. (2) Use `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to allocate a new console session hat has no window (i.e. `GetConsoleWindow()` returns `NULL`). (3) Use `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` and `startupinfo=STARTUPINFO(dwFlags=STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW)` to allocate a new console session with a hidden window.

Comment: For my purpose what worked was `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationfags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW`

Comment: You shouldn't use a pipe if you don't plan to read it dynamically, such as via `communicate`. A pipe has limited capacity (typically 4K). After it's full, writing to it blocks. This may block execution of the program. If you use the null device, the program can write to stdout or stderr without ever blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Eryk Sun comment, I had to use

```
subprocess.run(
    'subinacl.exe /service "foo" display',
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
)
```

Comment: Since it's writing to a console that has no window, redirecting the standard handles is optional. It may improve performance to redirect to the null device since the Windows console is the slowest terminal I've ever used, by far, but then you've got programs like subinacl.exe that directly open "CONOUT$" regardless of standard I/O.

Comment: Also, if a program might interact via stdin (e.g. paged output that requires the user to press a key), it may help to also redirect stdin to the null device, so that all reads return immediately as empty (EOF). If it instead opens "CONIN$" for this, you'd have to use `creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS` and hope the program can work correctly when opening "CONIN$" fails, which it will because there's no console session.